# How to add permission to editor user on Record Storage Page?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I am using TYPO3 version 9.5, and I am trying to show (enable) Record Storage Page for editor users inside plugin.

[image: This input is shown for admin]

So what I want to do is to show this input for a Used - Editor

```
 TCEMAIN {
     permissions.group = show,edit,delete,new,editcontent
     permissions.groupid = 1
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions on the fields of tables (like pages, tt_content, etc) are set at usergroup level, so you should edit the backend usergroup of your User Editor (located in the "root" folder) and go to the "Access List" tab.
Here you can set for the editors that belong to that group:

- allowed modules
- read and write permissions for the tables
- allowed page types
- allowed fields for every table (fields that are set with `exclude=>true` in TCA)
- allowed content types
- allowed languages

Comment: I missed that the problem was with User Storage Page (pages)- 
File collection. Thank you Problem solved